# Are there any language extensions or language descendants of Haskell, that favor expressiveness, particularly in instance handling?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, overlapping-instances

At times, I run into the "feature" that Haskell only matches instance heads, namely,

```
instance (a ~ NewDataTyp b) => C a
```

will now match any type whatsoever, i.e. writing another instance declaration of `C` in your program will *is an error*, even if it *cannot possibly* conflict due to the context `a ~ NewDataTyp b`. At times, it takes a lot of effort to overcome; I've had to restructure hundreds of lines of code to avoid this limitation.

Are there any language extensions, or descendant languages (Curry? Agda?) that are designed with a higher priority for expressiveness? This could possibly sacrifice (a) openness of the typeclass world (b) polynomial time typechecking.

**edit** -- for those interested in the question, this page might also be of interest: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Future_of_Haskell

Comment: Removing the open world assumption leads to [more problems than you might expect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728596/explicitly-import-instances/8731340#8731340). As far as I know, the only way to recover from that problem is to add full dependent types, and include the `Ord` instance being used in the `Set`'s type.

Comment: Haskell type checking is not polynomial, since HM type checking is (doubly) exponential.

Comment: I'm not sure if Chameleon had such an extension.  It requires the constraint solver to do backtracking, but I don't see any reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: @augustss, that sounds more like what I was looking for... will tell you when I have time to look

Comment: Agda may be more "expressive" in that the definition will be more concise in a case such as this where you would use GADTs.

Comment: If you what you want is _default base case plus extensible type based cases_ I'd go with SYB3 (i.e. SYB-with-class). Trying to achieve this with "OverreachingInstances" is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, Scala accepts the more-or-less literal translation of what you just wrote. I'm not sure how useful it is.

```
trait C[T]
case class NewDataType[T]()

implicit def letItBeInjectiveWhyNot[K[_],T]: K[T] =:= K[T]

implicit def cIsh[A,S](implicit ev: A =:= NewDataType[S]): C[A]
implicit def another: C[Int]

implicitly[C[NewDataType[String]]]
implicitly[C[Int]]
```