# any working operator overloading example in haskell

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading, overloading

I want to overload any operator . i want to do such a simple function that for instance think about overloading of == operator .Overload == such that
x==y
returns x . 
Or x==y return x+y. It doesn't matter what . Can you show me any simple operator overloading example? I cannot find any example on the web unfortunately.

For example;when i call Tree a == Tree a
return 5   (it always return 5. I select it ,it is not related to any thing)
or when i call 3==4
return : 7

I tried the below codes(i find it from haskell.org) but it cannot compile.

```
class Eq a where
(==) ::a -> a -> Int

instance Eq Integer where
x == y = 5

instance Eq Float where
x == y = 5
```

Neither the below code works:

data Tree a = Node a | Empty

class Tree a where
    (==) :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Int

instance Tree Integer where
x == y = 1

I take the error :

```
Ambiguous occurrence `Eq'
It could refer to either `Main.Eq', defined at Operations.hs:4:7
                      or `Prelude.Eq',
                         imported from `Prelude' at Operations.hs:1:1
                         (and originally defined in `GHC.Classes')
```

Comment: try only the instance parts. The typeclass definition is already made in Prelude. Alternatively, hide the import of the prelude definition.

Comment: then how to overload == for Trees and return always 5 ?

Comment: The `Eq` class defined in the Prelude requires that the result of `==` is a `Bool`, so to return `5` you'd have to hide that and define your own.

Comment: If you make == mean something other than equality, your code will be hard to understand. Consider using === instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't hide instances from an imported module. See for example: [Explicitly import instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728596/explicitly-import-instances)

It looks like the "overloading" you're trying to do is to allow `(==)` for other types, like trees. This is easy! Just simply create a new instance:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch [Tree a]

 instance (Eq a) => Eq (Tree a) where
    (Leaf a)   == (Leaf b)   = a == b
    (Branch a) == (Branch b) = a == b
    _          == _          = False
```

(You could also just `derive` the `Eq` instance)

Comment: do we have to write anything for overloading of == in module? For example; module x (f) where f a = a  . And the above code exists. Do we have to such a thing module x (f,'==') where ...

Comment: @user1308990: No; we actually can't control when they're exported -- they're *always* exported. This is called the "open world assumption"

Comment: @amindfv, the "open world assumption" is actually something else—the assumption that new instances can always be added.

Answer (score 2):

Try hiding the `==` from the Prelude first. You only need a type class if you want it to work differently for different types.

```
import Prelude hiding ((==))

x == y = x
```

Comment: How to specify the types of x and y if x and y is type Tree? Tree a = Node a | Empty

Comment: @user1308990: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but you can just do the same as you would for any function. Operators only have slightly different syntax.

Comment: OK.I got it . i do it to understand how overloading works. Now it is clear. However , i have one question too and i commented the question below the @amindfv 's answer . Could you clear it? Thanks

Comment: @user1308990: No, you don't need to list `==` in the exports. Instances are exported automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a +++ operator that acts like the (++) operator used to append lists:

```
(+++) :: [a]->[a]->[a]
x +++ [] = x
[] +++ x = x
x  +++ y = (init x) +++ ((last x) : y)
```

Comment: What does this answer add to the previous ones?