# Should lens generation be treated like instances

Tags: haskell, lenses

I have a data type defined in another library.  I would like to hook into that datatype with a lens generated by the Control.Lens library.

Do I need to newtype my type in my code or is it considered safe to lens an already defined data type?

Comment: I would say it's safe to provide lenses (and other related things) for types that are already defined. In fact, the lens library does this (`[]`, `Maybe`, etc).

Comment: The only reason that it's not safe with instances is that instances are global and required to be unique. Lenses are neither global nor required to be the only one with their type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a newtype. There are actually many packages on hackage that define lenses for already existing types (for example, [`xml-lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-lens) or even `lens` itself).

The problem with defining instances is that there is no way to hide them. If you define lenses, you can just hide them when importing, like any other function:

```hs
import Module.Lens hiding (someGeneratedLens, ...)
```

This is not possible with instances (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8731340/2494803 for reasons). Lenses are also not required to be globally unique, unlike instances.