# How to disregard a standard module?

Tags: haskell, functor, either

As an exercise, I am trying to implement my own version of a standard Functor, in this case `Either`.

My code looks similar to the standard definition:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
  fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
  fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)
```

When I attempt to compile it I get the following error:

```
ghc --make either.lhs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( either.lhs, either.o )

either.lhs:14:12: error:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance Functor (Either a) -- Defined at either.lhs:14:12
      instance Functor (Either a) -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
make: *** [hs] Error 1
```

The compiler sees a conflict with the standard instance defined in Data.Either. This is despite that I do not actually import the Data.Either module in my code. I would like to compile and test my own Functor implementation -- is there some way that I can perhaps hide Data.Either from the compiler to avoid the conflict?

Comment: You can't access the `Either` type from that module, yet not have its related instances in scope. You should define your own `Either` type instead.

Comment: Relevant: [*Explicitly import instances*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8728596/2751851)

Comment: I got something to work by defining my own `Either'` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

#### Define your own `Either`.

```
module Foo where
import Prelude hiding (Either)

data Either a b = Left a | Right b

instance Functor (Either a) where ...
```

#### Define your own `Functor`.

```
module Bar where
import Prelude hiding (Functor)

class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance Functor (Either a) where ...
```

---

As you discovered, you can also just make up non-clashing names rather than hiding things from the `Prelude`. But learning to hide things is pretty important; for example, you'll see many programs doing this:

```
import Control.Category
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
```

That's because those programs want to use the more general `id` and `(.)` from `Control.Category` instead of the ones from the prelude.