# Type class instance redefining

Tags: haskell, duplicates, instance, monads, redefinition

1. I am trying to answer this question:
   "Given the algebraic data type

   ```
   data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
   ```

   pick the correct instance declaration that shows that the type constructor `Maybe` is a `Monad`." (taken from here:"DelftX: FP101x Introduction to Functional Programming".
2. The way I am trying to anwer it is by compiling each potencial answer in turn, for example, this one:

   ```
   instance Monad Maybe where
              return x = Just x
              Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
              (Just x ) >>= f = f x
   ```
3. I can not compile it because it is already defined in the prelude.

   ```
   HwEx9.hs:16:10: error:
       Duplicate instance declarations:
         instance Monad Maybe -- Defined at HwEx9.hs:16:10
         instance Monad Maybe -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
   ```

My question is: How can I compile it?

Comment: Easiest way: Define your own `Maybe`-like type.

Comment: There's no way to avoid importing a typeclass instance for a given type. (see further https://stackoverflow.com/a/8731340/6476589)

Comment: Change it to MyMaybe?

Answer (score 7):

I would simply **mimic the `Maybe` datatype**, like:

```
data Maybe' a = Just' a | Nothing' deriving Show

instance Monad Maybe' where
    return x = Just' x
    Nothing' >>= _ = Nothing'
    (Just' x) >>= f = f x
```

In the last versions of `ghc`, this will fail, since the last versions require that you implement applicative as well. We can do this like:

```
instance Applicative Maybe' where
    pure = Just'
    (Just' f) <*> (Just' x) = Just' (f x)
    _ <*> _ = Nothing'
```

`Applicative` requires the type to be an instance of `Functor`, so we can implement it like:

```
instance Functor Maybe' where
    fmap f (Just' x) = Just' (f x)
    fmap _ Nothing' = Nothing'
```

It will then compile. The advantage of this approach is furthermore that we can easily compare the two `Maybe` monads, for example:

```
*Main> Just 2 >>= (\x -> Just (x+1))
Just 3
*Main> Just' 2 >>= (\x -> Just' (x+1))
Just' 3
```

Comment: Following your advice (Thank you), How would you mimic the list Monad, given as follows:instance Monad [] where  
    return x = [x]  
    xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)

Comment: `data List' = Empty' | Cons' a (List' a)`.

Comment: Shouldn't be: data List' a = Empty' | Cons' a (List' a) (Thank you for a quick answer).

Comment: It Does not Work:

 Here is the Code (taken from here :https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/13-the-list-monad)

data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

instance (Show a) => Show (List a) where
    show Nil = ""
    show (Cons x xs) = show x ++ ", " ++ show xs

instance Functor List where
    fmap f Nil = Nil
    fmap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (fmap f xs)

instance Applicative List where
    pure = Cons x Nil
    (List f) <*> (List x) = List (f x)
    _ <*> _ = Nil

 (errors : Not in scope: data constructor `List')

Comment: It Does not Work:

 Here is the Code (taken from here :https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/13-the-list-monad)

data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

instance (Show a) => Show (List a) where
    show Nil = ""
    show (Cons x xs) = show x ++ ", " ++ show xs

instance Functor List where
    fmap f Nil = Nil
    fmap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (fmap f xs)

instance Applicative List where
    pure = Cons x Nil
    (List f) <*> (List x) = List (f x)
    _ <*> _ = Nil

 (errors : Not in scope: data constructor `List')